# What are some words with the connotation of unreality/numbness/dream?

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language, idiom-request, metaphors, connotations

> Our world is only a **reflection**.

I'm looking for a word that could replace *reflection* here so that it would be still clear it's supposed to indicate numbness/unreality/fiction - that it's meant to mean the reflection *of the true reality*. What about glimpse? Gleam? Smear?

Comment: See [the Allegory of the Cave, or Plato's Cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_Cave). But there's a huge semantic gulf between ***numbness*** and ***reflection***, for example, which makes me think your question is an open-ended request for relevant *ideas*, rather than asking for a ***specific word*** to represent a specific *clearly-defined* concept.

Comment: Beat me to it, @FumbleFingers. Good job.

Comment: **...is only an illusion**.  Or we can use several of your words: *We get mere glimpses of the real world; we see it as if through a lens smeared with vaseline*.

Comment: @Robusto: Like jokes, vines, and wines, the old *ideas* are often the best ones. I believe theoretical physicists and materials scientists are still getting plenty of mileage out of [Platonic solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid), for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context I think you mean, I would suggest:

- Construct
- Representation
- Depiction
- Aberration
- Fantasy
- Delusion

Comment: _Shadow_ might work, too.